# URI Scheme opened by browser keep closing my C# App

Tags: c#, winforms, uri

I've developed an Winform C# application that can be opened by URI Scheme.
It's working when I launch it using the windows run dialog "Win+R" or using a standard launch process from an other c# app ex :

```
      Process process = new Process();
      ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

      startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
      startInfo.FileName = $"myapp:{server},{info}";

      process.StartInfo = startInfo;
      process.Start();

      process.Close();
```

the problem come when i try to launch it with a web browser or even windows file explorer : It launch the App and close immediatly. it do not pass by form_closing event and not by the log line after my application.Run(). so it seem to be killed.

here the program.cs :

```
static class Program
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Point d'entrée principal de l'application.
  /// </summary>
  [STAThread]
  static void Main()
  {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.File(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "LogFiles", $"{DateTime.Now.Year}-{DateTime.Now.Month}-{DateTime.Now.Day}", "Log.txt"),
        rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Infinite,
        outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
    .CreateLogger();

    try {
      Log.Information("Start");
      Application.Run(new frmMain());
      Log.Information("End");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Log.Error(ex, "FATAL ERROR"); }

  }
}
```

Can someone can explain me how to handle this situation ?
My goal is to be able to launch my app using a webbrowser extension ( that par is done ).

I'm expecting the app to stay open, unless closed by the user.

it's reproductible with Edge, Chrome, Windows Explorer

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Post the Registry settings and what happens when the starting Form is initialized (its Constructor) -- Does the Logger service register the startup information? Make sure the application is manifested (there's an `app.manifest`)

Comment: Hello @Jimi, I was no able to reproduce it with a brand new project.

So i started removing code from my app and out that the working directory when launching with a browser was not the app directory. it was system32. i was not able to trap it using Serilog because the error was happening in a separate thread,

here the error : 
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\bearer.json' is denied.

Ive been able to make it work now. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Yep, you probably have a .NET Framework application. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` is Thread-based. Probably `Application.StartupPath` (since it uses the Module File Name) may get the result you're expecting. Note, however, that when you deploy, you may not have access to that path either. Better do the logging in AppData or in the common area, `ProgramData` . See the other standard paths that the `Application` class gives you